# Using private dependencies with Codemagic

Tags: flutter, codemagic

I have a private repositories as Flutter packages in my app. Those packages are in bitbucket and codemagic fails to get them.

```
Warning: Permanently added 'bitbucket.org' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I wasn't able to find any examples or tutorials and documentation on it doesn't look clear to me.

[Related codemagic documentation](https://docs.codemagic.io/knowledge-git/private-packages/)

I've added my private ssh key for bitbucket, which has access to those dependencies.

I added them on Environment variables in app settings, as per the documentation suggests.
[image]

Documentation also mentions selecting a group name before adding it. I don't see any group name option on the UI.

```
Enter the variable group name, e.g. module_credentials. Click the button to create the group.
```

It also asks to put group name in the .yaml file, which is empty at this point since I'm solely using workflow editor.

My questions are:

1. Where's that group option? How I can add group?
2. If adding in .yaml is mandatory, do I need to start the .yaml file from scratch or just adding the variable group name is enough?

> ```
>   environment:
>         groups:
>         - module_credentials
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I recently encountered a similar issue with my application (self-hosted GitLab and onepub.dev for the private repo). I was unable to solve it using the Codemagic workflow editor. However, when switching to YAML configuration mode, I was able to add environment variables with groups ([https://codemagic.io/app/{appId}/settings](https://codemagic.io/app/%7BappId%7D/settings) -> tab: environment variables). I added my GITLAB_SSH_KEY to the group of my project and then I didn’t have the problem.

I believe that once you switch to YAML configuration mode, you are required to write your entire workflow. Here is an example of what I did:

```yaml
workflows:
  web-preproduction:
    name: Build and deploy 
    instance_type: mac_mini_m1
    max_build_duration: 10
    triggering:
      events:
        - push
      branch_patterns:
        - pattern: develop
          include: true
      cancel_previous_builds: true
    environment:
      groups:
        - your_environment
    scripts:
      - name: Install OnePub
        script: dart pub global activate onepub
      - name: Import OnePub token
        script: onepub import
      - name: Get Flutter Package
        script: flutter pub get
      - name: Build web
        script: |
          flutter config --enable-web
          flutter build web --release
          cd build/web
          7z a -r ../web.zip ./*
      - name: Install Deploy
        script: dart pub global activate deploy 0.0.1
      - name: Deploy Web Preprod
        script: dart pub global run deploy

    artifacts:
      - build/*.zip
```

I haven't explored Codemagic extensively, I have used it to create a pre-production version (with Flutter Web) every time I push changes to a specific branch. I hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I probably need to switch to yaml since UI definitely missed that option.